# dynamically DropDown options doesn't refreshed Immediately on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I use jqGrid on my project, and the grid has dependent dropdowns like this: parent's option=US,UK and child's option=Alabama,California,London,Oxford and so on.
child's optioins are set by "dataurl" option.
data will changes when object is created, and parent dropdown is changed.

I have a probrem when I run this Project on IE11.
If I run this on Firefox, options will be changed automatically, but IE11 doesn't do that.

IE11' behavior is like this:

1. first, options are set when object is created. but in this time, parent value is null too so child value isn't filtered(this is correct, same as Firefox).
2. Then User clicks on child dropdown and the event that changes child's option will be called.
3. But child dropdown list just shows every options(Alabama,California,London,Oxford...) whatever is chosen on parent dropdown. I expect that child dropdown shows Alabama,California when chosen "US" on parent dropdown.
4. and then, child shows correct options when dropdown is reopened.

I try that `blue()` for reopen child after click, but I can't find the way that open dropdown programmatically.

unfortunately, update jqGrid and using "free jqGrid" instead of jqGrid doesn't solved this probrem.

I'm sorry for my English, but I'm stuck because of this, I'm so happy if you help me.

Comment: In this case it is recommended to publish a demo case with code and data, which demonstrates the problem. It is very difficult to represent all user specific cases or if we try to do this we will lost all day long.

Comment: @TonyTomov thank you Tony, I'll try what you said. but my project is for my company, so it will taken little more time.